# handle words with accents

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to access a field by the display name that is a link, something like this:

`<a class="node" href="javascript: MCMenu(7);">MÓVEL</a>`

and trying to access the item by doing this:

`t= $browser.link(:text => "MÓVEL").exists?`

`t.click`

the error is:

unable to locate element, using {:text=>"M\303\223VEL", :tag_name=>"a"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)

Comment: What version of Ruby and Watir-WebDriver do you use? I just checked and it works fine for me.

Comment: Have you tried using the other set of quotes? I.e. 'movel' instead of "movel" ?

Comment: I'm using watir-webdriver (0.5.2, 0.4.1, 0.3.9) and ruby ruby 1.8.7

Comment: with the change of the quotes didnt work too

Comment: i have uninstaled the 0.41 and 0.39 now i only have the 0.52 but it does the same

Comment: I just checked with Ruby 1.8.7 and Watir-WebDriver 0.5.2 and it still works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with a regex like this:

```
t = $browser.link(:text => /M.VEL/).exists?
```